# Why does strip() method returns a list from a list of words?

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

I was trying to make a list with each char of a sentence.

Given the sentence `"7h3 qu1ck brown fox jumps ov3r 7h3 lazy dog"`

I used the `.split()` method to separate the words and afterwards another `.split()` method:

```
x = [i.split() for i in sentence]
```

and it returned:

```
[['7'], ['h'], ['3'], [], ['q'], ['u'], ['1'], ['c'], ['k'], [], ['b'], ['r'], ['o'], ['w'], ['n'], [], ['f'], ['o'], ['x'], [], ['j'], ['u'], ['m'], ['p'], ['s'], [], ['o'], ['v'], ['3'], ['r'], [], ['7'], ['h'], ['3'], [], ['l'], ['a'], ['z'], ['y'], [], ['d'], ['o'], ['g']]
```

So I was trying to figure out  why this was happening and tried with:

```
[i.strip() for i in sentence if len(i) > 0]
```

and it returned:

```
['7', 'h', '3', '', 'q', 'u', '1', 'c', 'k', '', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', '', 'f', 'o', 'x', '', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', '', 'o', 'v', '3', 'r', '', '7', 'h', '3', '', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', '', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

1. The first issue I'm facing is that I don't know why is returning empty strings.
2. The second issue is that I don't know why strip() behaves differently than `.split()`. I think that maybe it can be related to the return statement of each method, but I would like to understand better why this happen.

Answer (score 1):

[`.split(delim)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes in a string and returns a list of substrings that are between `delim`. [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will remove any leading or trailing whitespace from the string and return the resulting string.

The first issue you encountered was that you were splitting the string incorrectly. In `x = [i.split() for i in sentence]`, you iterate over every **character** of `sentence`, not every word. So, `i.split()` is attempting to split a single character by nothing. This doesn't make much sense, so it just returns a list with that character. See this below:

```
>>> sentence = '7h3 qu1ck brown fox jumps ov3r 7h3 lazy dog'
>>> [i for i in sentence]
['7', 'h', '3', ' ', 'q', 'u', '1', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'x', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', ' ', 'o', 'v', '3', 'r', ' ', '7', 'h', '3', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g']
>>> sentence.split(' ')
['7h3', 'qu1ck', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'ov3r', '7h3', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

Instead, you want to split by each space character (`' '`) to get a list of each word:

```
x = sentence.split(' ')
```

In response to what you were trying to do:

> I was trying to make a list with each char of a sentence.

All you need to do is convert the string to a list with `list()`. For example:

```
>>> list('7h3 qu1ck brown fox jumps ov3r 7h3 lazy dog')
['7', 'h', '3', ' ', 'q', 'u', '1', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'x', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', ' ', 'o', 'v', '3', 'r', ' ', '7', 'h', '3', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

If you first want to split by each word, then get each character of of each word, then do this:

```
>>> [list(word) for word in '7h3 qu1ck brown fox jumps ov3r 7h3 lazy dog'.split()]
[['7', 'h', '3'], ['q', 'u', '1', 'c', 'k'], ['b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n'], ['f', 'o', 'x'], ['j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's'], ['o', 'v', '3', 'r'], ['7', 'h', '3'], ['l', 'a', 'z', 'y'], ['d', 'o', 'g']]
```